# How to alter SQL in "Edit Top 200 Rows" in SSMS 2008

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2008

In SQL Server 2008 Management Studio, when I right click on a database table and choose **Select Top 100 Rows**, I can then e.g. easily add a `ORDER BY` statement to the SQL. That works fine.

But when I do choose **Edit Top 200 Rows**, I don't have the ability to alter the SQL (which makes it hard to find and edit a record just added in the 10,000 that are there.

I am quite sure I was able to do this in **SQL Server 2000**.

**Is there any way in SMSS 2008 to alter the way the records are displayed when editing records?**

Answer (score 331, accepted):

If you right click on any result of "Edit Top 200 Rows" query in SSMS you will see the option "Pane -> SQL". It then shows the SQL Query that was run, which you can edit as you wish.

It's the SQL button on the following image:
[image]

In SMSS 2012 and 2008, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> to quickly get there.

Comment: To refresh the results after editing the query, you need to right-click and select `Execute SQL` (Or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl+R)

Comment: This answer its even better, it allows you to actually Edit the query
    SELECT top 500 ***
    SELECT top 1000 *** WHERE ***

Comment: Is it possible to have Pane -> SQL as default when using "Edit top 200 rows"?

Comment: Great answer!!--very useful b/c it shows an EDIT grid.  afaik it's completely undocumented. (also nowhere else in ssms do you get an edit grid with a composable sql of the rows you want in the edit grid). This shouldn't be so buried in the SSMS gui. (Still works on the latest ssms and sql server 2019.)

Comment: this is perfect!  Late to the game but this is still a really helpful answer

Answer (score 169):

You can also change the pop-up options themselves, to be more convenient for your normal use.  Summary:

1. Run the SQL Management Studio Express 2008
2. Click the Tools -> Options
3. Select SQL Server Object Explorer . Now you should be able to see the options

   - Value for Edit Top Rows Command
   - Value for Select Top Rows Command
4. Give the Values 0 here to select/ Edit all the Records

Full Instructions with screenshots are here:  http://m-elshazly.blogspot.com/2011/01/sql-server-2008-change-edit-top-200.html

Comment: Not found http://m-elshazly.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/sql-server-2008-change-edit-top-200.html

Comment: @nag - This is a good answer for permanent changes to the buttons, but sometimes I want to make changes to a small subset of rows while looking at others. The answer by David Hall makes this possible by simply adding `Where ID in (1,2,3,4,5)` or something similar.

Answer (score 34):

Very **quick** and **easy visual instructions to change** this (and the select top 1000) for 2008 R2 *through SSMS GUI*

http://bradmarsh.net/index.php/2008/04/21/sql-2008-change-edit-top-200-rows/

Summary:

- Go to Tools menu -> Options -> SQL Server Object Explorer
- Expand SQL Server Object Explorer
- Choose 'Commands'
- For 'Value for Edit Top  Rows' command, specify '0' to edit all rows

Comment: This is the only option that seemed to work in the SQL Server Management Studio in 2020

Answer (score 15):

[image]

Follow the above image to edit rows from 200 to 100,000 Rows

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> in SQL Server 2012. Might work in 2008 too

Answer (score 8):

in SQL 2017 You can do it more easily  in the toolbar to the right  just hit
[image]

the SQL  button  then its gonna apear  the query with the top 200 you edit until the  quantity that You want and Execute the query and  Done! just Edit

Answer (score 5):

Similar to David Hall's response, if you are a non-coder, it may be easiest to right-click within results, then choose Pane > Criteria. This allows you to adjust sort, add filters, etc... without adjusting SQL code.

Answer (score 4):

The default to open/add rows to a table is Edit Top 200 Rows. If you have more than 200 rows, like me now, then you need to change the default setting. Here's what I did to change the edit default to 300:

1. Go to Tools in top nav
2. Select options, then SQL Service Object Explorer (on left)
3. On right side of panel, click into the field that contains 200 and change to 300 (or whatever number you wish)
4. Click OK and voila, you're all set!